# Increasing the color codes dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list and I'm trying to increase the color codes dynamically using rgb color codes,instead of using li:nth child css.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var items = $('#navigation li');
 var colorCode =0;
items.each(function (i, e) {
     colorCode++;  
     alert(colorCode)
    $(this).css("background-color", "rgb( "+colorCode + "," + colorCode + "," + colorCode + ")");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li>
     hello
    </li>
    <li>
     hello123
    </li>
    <li>
    hello345
    </li>
    <li>
   hello456
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Problem is that the counter colorcode is increasing but it shows black color for all the li elements.

Comment: Why not css? As that is perfect for the situation.

Comment: You simple don't realize the difference in 0, 1, 2 RGB color, when you use 10, 20, 30, you will see the difference.

Comment: Actually it's not black, but `rgb(4, 4, 4)`. Try to use this code on 50+ elemens and you will surely see the difference. Note: since you are using same color code for R, G and B, then your result will be the scale from black through gray to white.

Comment: i think the rgb syntax is numeric values from 0 to 255, you might be getting the right colors, different very dark greys

Comment: I'm just trying to achieve  this with jquery :)

Comment: You have a range from 0-255. You need to decide yourself how to use this. Have nothing todo with jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your `<li>` elements using some browser [dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) , you'll see that the color styles are set correctly according to your algorithm--just the colors are too similar to black, so they appear all black to you.

You can see that if you add more than 1 to each color part, the change in color becomes visible.

You could also define your colors in an array and your function could just return the `i-th` color that you define; it might be easier to define a good looking color scheme than to compute the color values manually like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var items = $('#navigation li');
 var colorCode =0;
items.each(function (i, e) {
     colorCode += 64;  
    $(this).css("background-color", "rgb( "+colorCode + "," + colorCode + "," + colorCode + ")");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li>
     hello
    </li>
    <li>
     hello123
    </li>
    <li>
    hello345
    </li>
    <li>
   hello456
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.Got it." colors in an array", Yea,I have tried that option,I'm just trying to do without array,li:nth child and stuffs.Just checking :)

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, you need more elements to see colors. I used 255 elements in the simple example, so you can see them all:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        $('#navigation li').first().clone().appendTo('#navigation');
    }

    var colorCode = 0;

    $('#navigation li').each(function (i, e) {
        colorCode++;
        $(this).css("background-color", "rgb( "+colorCode + "," + colorCode + "," + colorCode + ")");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```